# UITableViewCell subclass throwing an unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: uitableview, xib, unrecognized-selector

My UITableViewCell is giving a -[UITableViewCell nameTeam]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I created a PlayerStatsTableViewCell.xib with a UITableViewCell and UILabel.  Set the Custom Class to "PlayerStatsTableViewCell" and its Table View Cell identifier to "playerStats"

PlayerStatsTableViewCell.h

```
@interface PlayerStatsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameTeam;
@end
```

PlayerStatsTableViewCell.m

```
@implementation PlayerStatsTableViewCell
@synthesize nameTeam;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

In my PlayerStatsTableViewController, cell.nameTeam is throwing the error

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PlayerStatsTableViewCell *cell = (PlayerStatsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"playerStats"];
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PlayerStatsTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"playerStats"];

    cell.nameTeam.text = @"PLEASE";

    return cell;
}
```

PlayerStatsTableViewCell.xib showing Custom Class and Identifier

[image]
[image]

The error message
[image]

PlayerStatsTableViewController from Storyboard
[image]

Comment: no need to write "[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PlayerStatsTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"playerStats"];"

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PlayerStatsTableViewCell *cell = (PlayerStatsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"playerStats"];
    if (cell == nil) {
          NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PlayerStatsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
          cell = (PlayerStatsTableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.nameTeam.text = @"PLEASE";

    return cell;
}
```